# jquery - how to create condition in success function

Tags: php, jquery

I want to create jquery ajax success function based resp from logout.php. If users not sign in,It redirect bring them to login page.,but it's not working as I'm expected,no event occur when user is logged or not.So, what is wrong with my ajax function?

logout.php

```
<?php
    if( !$user->is_logged ) {
        echo 'true';
    }else{
        echo 'false';
    }
?>
```

jquery function in index.html

```
$(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "logout.php", 
    success: function(resp){
      if(resp =='true'){
        document.location = '../login_test.html';
      }
      if(resp=='false'){
         alert('U are logged');
        }           
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: do success: function(resp){
      console.log(resp); and show us

Comment: Also: are you sure the call succeeded? Add an `error:` handler and see if *that's* being called instead.

Comment: *So, what is wrong with my ajax function?* - it depends on how your *logout.php* is implemented

Comment: @phts You *did* notice that `logout.php` is included, apparently in full, in the question?

Comment: did you start the session?

Comment: why not just pass that boolean and encode the response as json

Comment: Try trimming `resp` before comparing it. There is often unwanted whitespace.

Comment: Where $user is declared in your php?

Comment: Oh,thanks,many feedback here,Actually $user define in user class,and logout.php working well, I just want to use html file,that why I'm called it using ajax.

Comment: Thanks all,It's working right now,as @TiiJ7 said, just add resp.trim() :)

Answer (score 1):

Change some errors and made it to better view:

PHP:

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  if( !$user->is_logged ) {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ok'));
  }else{
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'bad'));
  }
?>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "logout.php", 
    success: function(resp){
      var state = JSON.parse(resp).status
      if(state == 'ok'){
        document.location.href = '/login_test.html';
      }
      else{
         alert('U are logged');
      }           
    }
  });
});
```

If you have no alert, and have no redirect - you have not `.success` callback, and problem one level above your condition. In that case show us your errors from js-dev-console from browser.

Comment: thanks legendary,but not working when I convert it as your code.
But it's working right now, I just add resp.trim()     :)

Comment: Glad for you, trim save a lot of php-guys

Comment: @adam glad to hear it, learn and study - that's what all coders do:)